# Программа про лабиринт, можно ли что то сделать с этим дублированием?

Tags: c#

А именно методы  MoveRight и MoveDown.

```
using System;

namespace Mazes
{
public static class EmptyMazeTask
{
    public static void MoveOut(Robot robot, int width, int height)
    {
        MoveRight(robot, width);
        MoveDown(robot, height);
    }

    ***private static void MoveRight(Robot robot, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count - 3; i++)
        {
            robot.MoveTo(Direction.Right);
        }
    }
    private static void MoveDown(Robot robot, int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count - 3; i++)
        {
            robot.MoveTo(Direction.Down);
        }***
    }
}
}
```

Comment: передавай Direction как параметр

Comment: Спасибо за совет, попробую разобраться в этом не легком для меня вопросе

Comment: Собственно, `Robot.MoveTo` как-раз этот параметр и принимает )  Можно у него подсмотреть, хотя тут ничего сложного

Comment: Честно, понимания вообще пока полный 0

Comment: Добавить в функцию один параметр. Ну, почитайте про параметры функций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Честно, понимания вообще пока полный 0

А здесь вообще особых знаний не надо, всё просто

```
private static void MoveRobot(Robot robot, Direction direction, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 3; i++)
    {
        robot.MoveTo(direction);
    }
}

public static void MoveOut(Robot robot, int width, int height)
{
    MoveRobot(robot, Direction.Right, width);
    MoveRobot(robot, Direction.Down, height);
}
```

Comment: По такому же принципу переделывал змейку, но 3 теста не проходит

Comment: @Stroke задайте новый вопрос

Comment: создал, никто кроме вас не справился